# Is stringA in StringB in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab

Is there a way to check if a string exists within another string in MATLAB. In python this is done easily with a in b. I do not want indexes or anything like that. I just want to check if its true or not. The answers that I find is "strcmp" or "strfind" and also regexp. regexp returns indexes. strcmp(a, b) does not seem to work. I have a string a = 'ac' and another string b = 'bc_gh_ac'. And want to check if a in b.

Best regards

Comment: Also `strfind` http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html

Comment: Yes, this one does return indices, however, it does not return true if stringA is in stringB. But the solution was given by @Dave below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is indeed strfind.  You have to be careful with the order of the parameters which at first seems unusual - the pattern is the *second* argument, not the first.  The following code demonstrates:

```
a='ac';
b='bc_gh_ac';
strfind(b,a)
```

If you simply want to test whether the string is present or not then use the isempty function:

```
if ~isempty(strfind(b,a))
    disp('String is present');
end
```

Comment: Yes, strfind returns indices. However, the second solution, ~isempty() did the job! Thanx for that. And so its clear that there is no built-in function that returns true if one string is in another?

Comment: also you could wrap a `logical()` around your `strfind()` if you dont want an index back

Comment: @Finn's solution gave the desired results as well as the ~isempty(strfind()) solution. However, logical(strfind()) is nicer in someway.

Comment: Unfortunately @Finn's solution doesn't work as logical returns an array of the same dimensions as the input array.  So, if strfind gets no matches and returns an empty array, then logical(strfind()) also returns an empty array.  If strfind gets multiple matches, returning an array of values, then logical will return an array of logical values of the same length.  `isempty` is the Matlab recommended way of returning true for any matches, and returning false if there are no matches.  (isempty returns a boolean value)

Comment: @Dave is correct the `logical()` cant deal with the empty. how about `any(strfind())`? it would be logical, deal with empty deals and multiple entries

Comment: @Granit _there is no built-in function that returns true if one string is in another_ Note that the output of `strfind` can be used as if it were the logical value that you want. In other words, `if strfind(b,a)` works the same as `if ~isempty(strfind(a,b)))`. This is because a numerical array in Matlab is "truthy" if and only it is non-empty and all its elements are nonzero, and is "falsey" otherwise. So the array of indices returned by `strfind` works

Comment: I understand Luis. Thanx for the info. strfind() returns 1 if stringA is in stringB. That is comparable to "true" in a conditional. However, it returns empty [ ] if the string is not in stringB. Anyway, as I use it now, embedded in logical(), it gives the desired result.

Comment: @Granit, No, strfind does not return 1 if str2 is found in str1, instead it returns the index where string2 starts in string1, which will be a positive integer or empty if it's not found. Note that **because Matlab starts indexing with 1** (instead of most languages that start with 0) then you can plug the output diretly to an `if` conditional, since the returned value will always be greater than 0 is the string is found.